# showing json array data from mysql database to laravel blade view

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

Here is the Migration file, I have stored two numbers as json in mysql database, ["1234","4568"].
like this the O/P 
I am getting is "[\"1234\", \"5678\"]" but I need to print 1234,5678

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('store', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->json('store_numbers');

    });

}
```

//blade view

```
@foreach($stores as $store)
     <tr>
         <td>{{ $store->store_id }}</td>
         <td>{{ json_encode($store->store_numbers)}}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@foreach($stores as $store)
     <tr>
         <td>{{ $store->store_id }}</td>
         @php $store_numbers= json_decode($store->store_numbers); @endphp
         @foreach($store_numbers as $store_number)
            <td>
                 {{$store_number}}
            </td>
         @endforeach
     </tr>
@endforeach
```